# error launching Gradle task 'launchIPhoneSimulator'

Tags: ios, iphone, gradle, javafx, gluon

I launched "launchIphoneSimulator" and I had this error:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':launchIPhoneSimulator'.

  > org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Command '/var/folders/9c/9rh9d4cd53bg71673y0q2zxh0000gn/T/ios-sim4818382531238666049 showdevicetypes' failed with output: 2017-01-05 14:55:59.035 ios-sim4818382531238666049[7983:422626] +[SimDeviceSet defaultSet]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x108f015b8
  >   2017-01-05 14:55:59.036 ios-sim4818382531238666049[7983:422626] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[SimDeviceSet defaultSet]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x108f015b8'
  >   *** First throw call stack:
  >   (
  >       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d2b3452 **exceptionPreprocess + 178
  >       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff958bef7e objc_exception_throw + 48
  >       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d31d00d +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
  >       3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d2234d1 ___forwarding_** + 1009
  >       4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d223058 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
  >       5   ios-sim4818382531238666049          0x0000000105e5ec21 -[iPhoneSimulator showDeviceTypes] + 75
  >       6   ios-sim4818382531238666049          0x0000000105e60dd1 -[iPhoneSimulator runWithArgc:argv:] + 3111
  >       7   ios-sim4818382531238666049          0x0000000105e60fb9 main + 101
  >       8   ios-sim4818382531238666049          0x0000000105e5e150 start + 52
  >   )
  >   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (Exit value: 134)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I need to do screenshots of my app for the app Store? How can I do?
Thank you

Comment: Go to your `SimDeviceSet` class. Make sure that you declared the function `defaultSet` and this function must be added to the .h file as well. You probably do a `performSelector` without checking the the selector is actually  declared in the target object's class.

Comment: What is your jfxmobile plugin version? Can you verify the iOS version under dependencies/compile for iOS?

Comment: in my build.gradle dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.1.1'
    }

Comment: Update to 1.3.1

Comment: now it works!! thanks!! But how I can change the simulator type?

Comment: See this [link](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_ios_4) for options to modify the simulator device or sdk